# Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin Security Context

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

How I can change securityContext of my pods in Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin. For example, run docker in docker images with privileged mode in docker environment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates) should work (as per the docs):

```
def label = "mypod-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
podTemplate(label: label, yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    some-label: some-label-value
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
"""
) {
    node (label) {
      container('busybox') {
        sh "hostname"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: in accually, I don't want to create another container template, may be I can handle this problem only with node definition . How can I run the pods with privileged mode .

Comment: Do you mean force `privileged mode` on all your pods at the node level?

Comment: Yes , I wanna handle the all jobs at node level .